# JavaScript: Return index position as 1 instead of 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, position, indexof

Given an array of strings, I am tasked with returning a string with `"The lucky person is number n in the list!"` if the string `"lucky"` appears within the array.

I have working code for this, however it is asking me to return "The lucky person is number 1 in the list!" when `arr = ["lucky"]`.

So far this is returning `"person is number 0"` as it is index position 0, so how can I alter the code to make this position count as 1 instead? Thank you!

```
function findLuckyPerson(arr) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] === 'lucky') {
       return "The lucky person is number " + arr.indexOf("lucky", 0) + " in the list!";
     } else {
       return "There is no lucky person in the list :("
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`(i + 1)` instead of `arr.indexOf("lucky", 0)` should do the trick.

Even more concise, get rid of the loop altogether

```
function findLuckyPerson(arr) {
   var i = arr.indexOf("lucky");
   if (i >= 0)
       return "The lucky person is number " + (i + 1) + " in the list!";
   else
       return "There is no lucky person in the list :("
}
```

Comment: I would suggest this as well. Keep it simple. No need to loop through an array if you're simply checking for a specific substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can add 1 in index position like following:

```js
var arr=['lucky','unlucky'];
function findLuckyPerson(arr) {
   for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
     if (arr[i] === 'lucky') {
       return "The lucky person is number " + (i+1) + " in the list!";
     } else {
       return "There is no lucky person in the list :("
     }
   }
}
console.log(findLuckyPerson(arr));
```